# "Not Authorized to access " error on create mutation + GraphQL

Tags: node.js, graphql, aws-appsync, graphql-js, aws-amplify-cli

I'm running the below GraphQL query to create data on dynamodb table, but gets the response with "Not Authorized to access createClient on type Client"

Why this is happening at.

GraphQL query:

```
`mutation addClient{
  createClient(input:{
    fullName: "Jhon Smith"
    title: "Software Engineer"
    organization: "AWS"
    contactNo: "+341289655524"
    email: "smithj@amazon.com"
    country: "Canada"
    address: "AN/458, Norton place, Down Town"    
  }){
    fullName
  }
}`
```

Response :

```
{
  "data": {
    "createClient": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "createClient"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "Unauthorized",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Not Authorized to access createClient on type Client"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the HTTP client that sends the GraphQL query to the server need to also send an Authorization header with an authentication token? (or some other form of authentication)

Comment: Seems yes. it needs some autorization. Do you have any samples for that?

Answer (score 7):

It solved with authMode

`const newTodo = await API.graphql({ query: mutations.createClient, variables: {input: inputData}, authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS" });`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer worked for me, some more info in [the amplify docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/authz/q/platform/js/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your model `@auth` directive has `... operation: [create, ...]` included. This is what I was running into.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with the error -
error fetching {"data": {"createTodo": null}, "errors": [{"data": null, "errorInfo": null, "errorType": "Unauthorized", "locations": [Array], "message": "Not Authorized to access createTodo on type Mutation", "path": [Array]}]}

Turn out the amplifyconfiguration.json file had
"aws_appsync_authenticationType": "API_KEY"
where "API_KEY" shall be replaced with "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"